# Matlab memory management

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I am simulating a set of differential equations in Matlab, for which I will save a struct of  at least 400 x 80 000 x 24 doubles.

What in your opinion is the easiest way to control memory load? Memory mapping or a parallel process for memory checking, data writing and clearing? The program is single thread, but potentially will be re-written for a parallel computing.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? For me this will simply run: `clear;z=ones(400,80000,24);o=ones(400,80000,24);r=rand(400,80000,24);` so it should not require extreme measures to store your data. Or are you worried about memory intensive calculations? In that case please elaborate a bit.

Comment: As @DennisJaheruddin stated, 768,000,000 doubles is not particularly large. How are you storing these in a struct – as a single array? Do you know that memory is a bigger issue than the cost of evaluating your differential equations? Or are you running an old 32-bit version of Matlab on Windows?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, at the behest of my boss I put it in a struct, but it seems it occupies ~17 times memory. So instead of occupying 30 MB, the struct takes up over 500MB.  I guess that going to array is a solution, but *IF* I'd wanted do some memory management.

Comment: @horchler, see above. I'm running x64 on a 16GB ram setup. The PDE evaluation is already optimized in a mex/C function.

Comment: I'm guessing that it takes up more space in the struct because you don't have a single matrix in there, but instead many many little ones. At least on R2013a each field of a struct (element of a struct array) adds 176 bytes – the equivalent of 22 doubles. Structures can be useful and efficient (e.g., passing data into functions), but they have to used correctly. Matlab's ODE solvers, e.g., `ode45`, can return their data as a structure if only one output variable is requested. You might look at how they do it (i.e., for time `sol.x(i)` and the state vector solution is `sol.y(:,i)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem statement

Here are two problems, I think you are facing one of these:

1. Your data is really a block of mxnxz
2. Your data is not really a block of mxnxz

**Solution for 1**

If your data is really a block form, it is likely the best solution to store your data in a matrix.

**Solution for 2**

If your data is not a nice block, there are some choices to be made.

If your data is nearly a nice block, (for example mx(0.99~1.01)nxz, still consider using a matrix. Think about padding the gaps with zeros or `NaN` values.

If your data is very much not a block, (for example mx(0.01~100)nxz, consider using a more flexible data structure.

---

### **On flexible data structure usage**

The trick to using data in a flexible way, is to try to identify the big matrices (that may vary in size) and let those be regular matrices. In your case the data is about 400 x 80000 x 24, hence you will definitely want the 80000 to be the dimension of a simple storage structure. The 24 and 400 are quite small so we don't care whether they are flexible or not.

---

### **Conclusion**

- The most efficient data structure that is not very flexible is a matrix of 400x80000x24
- The most flexible data structure that is still fairly efficient is a cell array of 400x24, that contains vectors of approximately 80000x1
- The most efficient data structure that is still fairly flexible is a cell array of 1x24 that contains matrices of approximately 400x80000. As 24 is small you could even use a struct for this in a meaningfull way, but usually a cell array will make more sense.